# Call npm.info(modulename) without printing result to stdout

Tags: node.js, npm

With a local installation of npm in `./node_modules/npm` and inside a default `node` shell,

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load({}, function (err, res) {
    npm.info('tennu');
}
```

the result of `npm.info()` will echo to `stdout` the same stuff that it would as if you called

```
npm info tennu
```

from the commandline.

How can I make npm not echo to stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `npm apihelp info`

```
require('npm').load({}, function (err, npm) {
    npm.commands.info(['tennu', 'version'], true, function (er, info) {
        console.error('the info was:', info)
    })
})
```